# Websockets for tags I searched for

Tags: bug, tags, search, new-nav, web-sockets

If I input tags on the tag page and connect them with `any` then I get new questions notifications through the web socket. [Example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql%20sql%20sql-server%20sqlite%20oracle%20sql-server-2008%20sql-server-2012%20sql-server-2008-r2?mode=any)

[image]

But if I search for tags and connect them in the search box with `OR`, then I do not get any web socket updates. [Example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%20or%20sqlite%20or%20mysql%20or%20oracle%20or%20sql-server%20or%20sql-server-2008%20or%20sql-server-2012)

[image]

Comment: As the socket can only subscribe to [one tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218355/158100) I guess the easiest thing to do was to stop subscribing to the websocket if there is a more complex search term in play.

Comment: This is a really annoying issue, so much so that I actually switched back to the old system, which handles this fine. Looking at the old system’s socket in the debugger, it just subscribes to the endpoint for each tag, which works fine.